# How to generate and read QR code from a unique id in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, qr-code

I need to create a QR code in the flutter app using a unique id generated when creating a document in firestore, i also want to add the functionality  be able to scan this generated QR code and retrieve the document id it was created with.